# GIT: How do I properly download a remote branch to local?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-pull, git-remote, git-fetch

Want to download another remote branch to make maintenace, then push back.

so I tried:

```
git switch another_branch
fatal: invalid reference: another_branch
```

tried:

```
git checkout --track origin/another_branch
fatal: 'origin/another_branch' is not a commit and a branch 'another_branch' cannot be created from it
```

tried:

```
git checkout another_branch
error: pathspec 'another_branch' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

tried:

```
git fetch origin another_branch:another_branch
From gitlab.my-inc.com:projname/proj
* [new branch]      another_branch   -> another_branch
git checkout another_branch
Switched to branch 'another_branch'
```

seems good but:

```
git pull
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories

git branch -vv
* another_branch            421f45e normal commit comments

git branch --set-upstream-to origin/another_branch
error: the requested upstream branch 'origin/another_branch' does not exist
hint:
hint: If you are planning on basing your work on an upstream
hint: branch that already exists at the remote, you may need to
hint: run "git fetch" to retrieve it.
hint:
hint: If you are planning to push out a new local branch that
hint: will track its remote counterpart, you may want to use
hint: "git push -u" to set the upstream config as you push.
```

so, I tried:

```
git fetch
git fetch origin another_branch
From gitlab.my-inc.com:projname/proj
* branch            another_branch   -> FETCH_HEAD
```

and still got:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to origin/another_branch
error: the requested upstream branch 'origin/another_branch' does not exist
hint:
hint: If you are planning on basing your work on an upstream
hint: branch that already exists at the remote, you may need to
hint: run "git fetch" to retrieve it.
hint:
hint: If you are planning to push out a new local branch that
hint: will track its remote counterpart, you may want to use
hint: "git push -u" to set the upstream config as you push.
```

Now I feel totally not human seeing others playing well with their git...

So please help, and thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you run `git fetch origin`? It seems you only specified the remote but this does not fetch said remote.

Comment: @SimonDoppler Thank you for the advice. Tried just now: `git fetch origin` (blank output), then `git branch --set-upstream-to xxx -> branch does not exsit` , and  `git pull -> refusing to merge unrelated histories`.

Comment: what do you see when you run `git branch -a | grep "another_branch"` and `git branch -a` ? as suggested by VonC : you may have a refspec which maps remote branches to a non standard name.

Comment: You probably made a single-branch clone: check the `remote.origin.fetch` setting, as VonC suggests.

Comment: @LeGEC grep returns blank result for "another_branch". seems to be the problem.

Comment: @torek You are right. this fixed everything!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as `git branch -avv` does not list `origin/another_branch`, a simple `git switch another_branch` will not work.

Its [guess mode](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch#Documentation/git-switch.txt---guess) would make that command as:

> If `<branch>` is not found, but there does exist a tracking branch in exactly one remote (call it `<remote>`) with a matching name, treat as equivalent to:
>
> ```
> $ git switch -c <branch> --track <remote>/<branch>
> ```

In your case, check the [refspec of your remote](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec)

```
git config remote.origin.fetch
```

Or, as [torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek) suggests in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71391150/git-how-do-i-properly-download-a-remote-branch-to-local/71391551#comment126233799_71391551), in case of multi-values:

```
git config --get-all remote.origin.fetch
```

It should be like

```
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Which means it should fetch *all* branches, instead of fetching only one branch, for instance:

```
+refs/heads/main:refs/remotes/origin/main
```

If it does not fetch all branches, set it using that refspec (`+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`), and a `git fetch` will be able to show you remote branches of the remote repository, including, hopefully, `origin/another_branch`

Comment: Minor: better to run `git config --get-all remote.origin.fetch` in case it is multi-valued. But I'm betting the OP has a single-branch clone, with `+refs/heads/main:refs/remotes/origin/main` or similar, as the only value.

Comment: @torek Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: wildcard works like a charm. now every branch is defined.